# PCL::MomentOfInertiaEstimation in ROS

Tags: pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I would like to use the MomentOfInertiaEstimation object from PCL. As I saw in pcl_ros this package only uses 1.7.0 of the pcl library. The object MomentOfInertiaEstimation is available from 1.7.2.
Is there any easy way to get the 1.7.2 version of pcl?

I'm using ROS Hydro

Thanks Johannes

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194930/pcl::momentofinertiaestimation-in-ros/) by [Johannes](https://answers.ros.org/users/2719/johannes/) on ROS Answers with karma: 75 on 2014-10-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you want to use a different version of pcl you will need to install it from source as well as any package which depends on it.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-11-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0